# Calculate length of an object comprised of pixels in all 8-neighbor-dimensions

Tags: python, jython, imagej, imaging

I have an array with 1s and 0s where the 0s represent background and 1s information that came originally from an image. I first find out which 1s belong together (thus are direct neighbors along their theoretic pixel sides or diagonally touching at their corners). All 'neighborhoods' get enumerated, so I can further get the sum, averages etc. per 'neighborhood'/label.

However, those values are supposed to represent pixel values and I would like to find out what their real length is as simply summing up the pixels underestimates their real length I need to find another way to calculate this. I looked into this but cannot find what exactly I would have to calculate to get the actual length. (I am not talking about normalizing the pixel values to their real dimensions.)

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
from skimage.measure import label
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

# example array where I need to find groups of neighbors
inters_array= ([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# structure array to deterimine neighbors in 8-dimensions
struc = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int)

# skimage function to get label objects, i.e. groups of neighbors
neighbors, ncomponents = label(inters_array, structure=struc)

""" where in theory it detects the groups of neighbors and gives them the same number
    as long as they are neighbors like so:
neighbors = ([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
                [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]) """

# measure.regionprops() will give me an object 
# as extraproperties I can add custom functions
regionpros = skimage.measure.regionprops(neighbors, intensity_image=None, cache=True, extra_properties=None)

# like the perimeter of each object
regionpros_peri = regionpros[0].perimeter
```